# Keyboard quickly hides and reappears on Android using Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-softkeyboard

We're trying to build a Chat App using Xamarin Forms, but we keep getting this annoying bug with the Android keyboard. Whenever the "Send" button is tapped, the focus on the Entry (text box for chatting) is lost and the keyboard disappears. That isn't what we wanted so we added this line to the TapGestureRecognizer:

```
messageEntry.Focus();
```

But for some reason, this doesn't happen fast enough, and often the keyboard goes down and immediately up again. This prevents users from quickly posting multiple message sequentially. Does anybody know how this can be fixed?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem

Comment: Never did, maybe it's possible using the platform specific API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the answer of @AdamKemp in this [post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/56523/entry-cell-loses-focus-on-button-press-in-android-but-not-ios-work-around), here is my solution. If the touch is within my `EntryStackLayout` (don't forget to create the empty custom renderer), then I don't dismiss the keyboard (which is what `DispatchTouchEvent` will do if `CurrentFocus` is `EditText`).

```
public class EditorAndButtonReproPage : ContentPage
    {
        public EditorAndButtonReproPage()
        {
            BackgroundColor = Color.Gray;
            Padding = 50;
            var editor = new Editor {HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand};
            var editorButton = new Button {Text = "OK", HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End};
            var editorLayout = new EntryStackLayout { Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal, Children = { editor, editorButton}, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start};
            var entry = new ExtendedEntry { Placeholder = "Entry", HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand };
            var entryButton = new Button { Text = "OK", HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End };
            var entryLayout = new EntryStackLayout { Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal, Children = { entry, entryButton }, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start };
            Content = new StackLayout {Children = {editorLayout, entryLayout}};
        }
    }
```

and in the `MainActivity`:

```
private bool _ignoreNewFocus;
        public override bool DispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
        {
            var currentView = CurrentFocus;
            var parent = currentView?.Parent?.Parent;
            var entryStackLayout = parent as EntryStackLayout;
            if (entryStackLayout != null)
            {
                var entryLayoutLocation = new int[2];
                entryStackLayout.GetLocationOnScreen(entryLayoutLocation);
                var x = e.RawX + entryStackLayout.Left - entryLayoutLocation[0];
                var y = e.RawY + entryStackLayout.Top - entryLayoutLocation[1];
                var entryStackLayoutRect = new Rectangle(entryStackLayout.Left, entryStackLayout.Top, entryStackLayout.Width, entryStackLayout.Height);
                _ignoreNewFocus = entryStackLayoutRect.Contains(x, y);
            }
            var result = base.DispatchTouchEvent(e);
            _ignoreNewFocus = false;
            return result;
        }

        public override Android.Views.View CurrentFocus => _ignoreNewFocus ? null : base.CurrentFocus;
```

Answer (score 0):

It'd be a bit of a hack, but you could spin off an async task that waits 50ms and then invokes the messageEntry.Focus() line on the main UI thread...