# Xamarin Keyboard Disappears then Appears

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When using entry.Focus() to move from one entry field to another is very janky. The keyboard disappears and then reappears.

I found someone who encountered the same issue but the proposed workaround didn't work for me.

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/10703

Any idea how to circumvent this issue?

Comment: This might help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27994030/keyboard-quickly-hides-and-reappears-on-android-using-xamarin-forms

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed.
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/11191

If you still have this issue, please try to use the lastest version of your Xamarin.Forms. I tested on Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2012 and Androoid 10.0. It works. You could check my screenshot. https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZAHZ.jpg